# Preview changes without saving while editing Wikipedia and other wiki-sites by Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

(English is not my native language, PROMT translate)

Hello, I edit sites with MediaWiki markup via Sublime Text 3 using the plugin [Mediawiker](https://github.com/tosher/Mediawiker). If I want to make a preview of the changes committed by me, I keep changes, press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> and see how it looks in a browser. Whether it is possible to make somehow a fast preview the page of the wiki-site with the changes made by me without saving of the page? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two days ago, 20.04.2016, the functionality was introduced in Mediawiker plugin. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> → <kbd>Page preview</kbd> . In russian Stack Overflow I wrote [Mediawiker Page preview manual](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/515714/199934).

[image: Mediawiker plugin]

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with a sublime text plugin for this (although I wouldn't be surprised if one existed), but this is a core feature of the [Brackets](http://brackets.io/) editor, which is free, if you want to give that a shot.

Comment: I do a set of other work in Sublime Text 3 therefore I would like to find the solution specifically for Sublime Text 3. Thanks.